# Adding variables together to perform a mathematical equation

Tags: javascript, calculator

I have recently been struggling with a calculator concept using JavaScript. I've tried lots of things, but just can't get it to work.

The calculator has three drop down lists: one for the first number (0-9), one for the operation and one for the second number (also 0-9). Basically, when you press the "Perform Equation" button, it gets the values of the drop down lists and supposedly adds up all those values, performing an equation. Here's an example, short and simple.

```
<select id="n1">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>

<select id="op">
<option value="+">0</option>
<option value="-">1</option>
</select>


<select id="n2">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Perform Equation" onclick="perform"/>

<p id="printE"/>

<script>
function perform() {
var analyseN1 = document.getElementById("n1").value
var analyseOp = document.getElementById("op").value
var analyseN2 = document.getElementById("n2").value
var addUp = analyseN1+analyseOp+analyseN2;
document.getElementById("printE").innerHTML= addUp;
}
</script>
```

As you can see, I get the values of all the drop downs, "add them up" and then print the final result. It's not working, however. Can someone please tell me why? I'm, well, not the best at JavaScript. I'm rather young and got introduced to the language only a couple of months ago. So yeah, if you know the answer, it would be awesome if you could tell me. Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Comment: `.value` gets you a string, using `+` with strings preforms string concatenation. You need to extract the number value - `parseInt` for integers and `parseFloat` for floating point numbers, for example.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with _"not working"_? What is happening, and what do you want to happen, instead?

Comment: To Cerbrus: I want to create a simple calculator. Instead it's printing out the string, not the result.

Comment: You guys are forgetting (/overlooking) that you can't parse a _operator_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There area  couple of issues here. One is that `+` has two meanings in Javascript. For numbers, it means "plus", just as you're intending. For strings, however, it means "concatenate".

So `1 + 1 = 2`, but `"1" + "1" = "11"`.

When you fetch the values from your `<select>` elements they will be retrieved as strings, so you need to parse them as integers using `parseInt` like this:

```
var analyseN1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value);
var analyseN2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n2").value);
```

The other issue is that to build up your equation, you're really building up a string of code to run.  Running a string of code *can* be done with `eval()`, but **it's terribly insecure, so nobody here will recommend it!**

You might end up having to do something like instead:

```
// Get the numbers from the selects, and the operator
var analyseN1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value);
var analyseOp = document.getElementById("op").value
var analyseN2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n2").value);

// Add or subtract the numbers, depending on the selected operator
var addUp;
if(analyseOp == "+"){
  addUp = analyseN1 + analyseN2;
}else{
  addup = analyseN1 - analyseN2;
}
```

Here's why you should avoid using `eval()`, even though it's the most direct answer to your question:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21

Comment: Personally, I'd advise against answering with ternary operators or other advanced syntax, when the OP is learning the basics of a language.

Comment: Taken on board @Cerbrus, and updated my answer accordingly. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

To actually perform the calculation, you need a little bit more code than this.

What you're doing right now, is getting the values from the `n1`, `op`, and `n2` elements. Then, you're basically combining those strings into a result.

To get the numeric value of the `n1` and `n2` strings, you'll need to use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
function perform() {
    var analyseN1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value, 10);
    var analyseOp = document.getElementById("op").value
    var analyseN2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n2").value, 10);
```

> From the MDN page:
>   *The `parseInt()` function parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix or base.*

Then, to use the proper operator, depending on the drop-down, you're going to need to compare the `analyseOp` value with a `"+"` and a `"-"` string:

```
    var addUp;
    if(analyseOp === '+'){
        addUp = analyseN1 + analyseN2;
    }else if(analyseOp === '-'){
        addUp = analyseN1 - analyseN2;
    }

    document.getElementById("printE").innerHTML= addUp;
}
```